# Comparing terms entered by the user to lists in a txt file

Tags: c++, search, text, getline

I'm want the user to enter in their name, sex, age, medication, and condition.  Then look through the text to see if their condition matches any of the other people in the text document, then see if their age, sex, or medication is the same.  If it is out put the possible side effect that's also in the text document.

Having trouble getting started since its been so long since I did anything like this. I just need to know the basics of how to read and compare a text document.

Txt doc is laid out like this:

```
Name Med Sex Age Cond Effect
Bill DepMed M 33 Depression StomachAche 
Tom ADDMed  M 24 ADD HeadAche
```

Comment: This isn't a free homework service. Please show us what you've tried so far to solve the problem, and why you're stuck. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Even if you can't figure out how to compare something to the contents of a file, at least you know how to open a file and read the contents into an array, right? Go ahead and code that first. If not, you need to review what you've learned so far since we can't teach you how to read files in a SO post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "basic" you need, but to read and write files you need to include the header file "fstream". You can read and write files in a variety of ways. One way is to open a file and instead of using `cin` for input and `cout` for output you would use the name of the file stream that you opened the file in. Example:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    string input;
    fstream dataFile; //names stream 'dataFile' sort of like a variable.

    dataFile.open("data.txt", ios::in | ios::out); //opens data.txt for reading (ios::in) and writing (ios::out)
    dataFile >> input; //stores data to input exactly like 'cin' would from the screen, but in this case the input is coming from 'dataFile'
    getline(dataFile, input, '\n'); //stores data to input exactly like 'cin.getline()' would
    dataFile << "String to be added in file" << endl; //prints to file exactly like 'cout' prints to screen
    dataFile.close() //closes file, be sure to do this or else you risk memory leak issues
}
```

Specifically for your question:

1. Ask the user for one of the columns (you don't need to ask for all of them. Name, condition, or symptom would work best).
2. Open data file
3. Use `getline(inFile, junk, '\n');` to skip first line (you don't want to search the column titles). `junk` is a string variable and `inFile` is your '.txt' file.
4. Read the next line in the file by using `getline()` again.
5. For every line, search the string that was read from the file, `searchString`, for the string that the user inputted, `userInput`, using `found = searchString.find(userInput, 0)`. You would have to declare `size_t found` before the loop.
6. For every line, check if `userInput` was found in `searchString` using `if(found != std::string::npos)`
7. If found print `searchString to the screen using 'cout'
8. Repeat step 4-7 until the end of file is reached
9. Close the file